# java writing to a file not working

Tags: java, file

I was wondering if anyone can take a look at my code and see what i'm doing wrong. I'm trying to get my program to write to a file but it wont. I need some help to get it to write the result to a file. Yes i know many questions have been asked about this and yes i looked at them, there's quite a few. I just cant really use there examples it doesnt make sense to me. Any help would be great.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class DistanceFile {    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int time; //hours traveled
        int hour;//for the formula
        String FileName;
        Scanner scanner= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the speed of the vehicle");
        int speed= scanner.nextInt();
        while (speed<=0){
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid speed");
            speed=scanner.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Enter the number of hours traveled");
        time=scanner.nextInt();
        while (time<=0){
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid time");
            time=scanner.nextInt();
        }
        hour=0;

        PrintWriter outputFile= new PrintWriter("DistanceFile.txt");
        for(  hour = 1; hour <= time; hour++)
            System.out.println(hour+ " " + (hour * speed));
        outputFile.print(speed+"");
        outputFile.print(time+" ");
        outputFile.close();
```

Comment: outputFile.flush() before you close

Comment: The `close()` method should be doing the flushing. What is the error? The file is not created at all, or is it created and does not contain the output expected?

Comment: The code seems to work for me (DistanceFile.txt is created in the working directory)

Comment: i created it i think

Comment: If it is created and you know where (i.e., in the working directory of your code), then you should be able to see the contents you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine. You should enter the whole file path like:

```
PrintWriter outputFile= new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\XXX\\Desktop\\test.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [BufferedWriter](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-bufferedwriter-example/).

Even after tweaking your code it still doesn't work, check if the place you're saving at can be written to. If your program is not allowed to, you could save in a different place or modify the folder settings.